# python; create list with number increasing by increment

Tags: python, list

I was trying to make a list in python looking like this;

['Product 1','Product 2','Product 3'......all the way to 10]

So far I've tried

```
[x for x in list(np.arange(1,11)) 'Product'+x ]
```

Is there a neat way of doing this?

Comment: I have two suggestions: 1) don't use `numpy` if you don't know what you are using it for, 2) search the web for "python list comprehension syntax", instead of guessing the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this.

```
[f"Product {x}" for x in range(1,11)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`["Product " + str(x) for x in range(1, 11)]`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer f strings, so I would do it:

```
[f'Product {i}' for i in range(1, 11)]
```

You can do it without f strings as well by casting the int to a string:

```
['Product ' + str(i) for i in range(1, 11)]
```